# Почему примеры на старых языках в верхнем регистре?

Tags: code-style, basic, oberon

```
PROCEDURE Store* (VAR W: Files.Rider; T: Text);
VAR p, q: Piece;
  R: Files.Rider;
  off, rlen, pos: LONGINT;
  N, n: INTEGER;
  ch: CHAR;
```

Оберон. Почитаешь о модуле - также, ключевые слова в верхнем регистре? Это просто такой дизайн, или действительно требования старых языков (Basic например)?

Comment: Не знаю точного ответа, но сделаю предположение. Когда то вывод осуществлялся на монохромные мониторы и принтеры, с жестко забитой таблицей символов. Выделять начертанием, или тем более цветом, было невозможно. Поэтому выделение верхним регистром было одним из немногих средств форматирования, совместимых, к тому же, для разных устройств.

Comment: На некоторых древностях со вводом через перфоленты, насколько мне помнится, вообще был один регистр... Впрочем, не уверен на 100%.

Comment: @Harry Именно так! И на перфокартах никакого нижнего регистра не было.

Comment: То есть это не требование языка? А то на GitHub лежит код Оберон2013 в таком стиле, я и подумал что это требование.

Comment: Про Оберон не знаю.

Comment: А такое может быть?

Comment: Пример точно живой и реальный? Вот это - `N, n: INTEGER;` - точно так?

Comment: Кстати, по поводу ZX-Spectrum, ключевые слова вставлялись по нажатию одной клавиши (ну или SS+клавиша, или режим E, или режим E+SS+клавиша), и начертание ключевых слов в верхнем регистре было зашито жестко.

Comment: @insolor, не во всех версиях zx-бэйсика

Comment: @Mirdin, предлагаю написать ответом.

Comment: @Harry, а `PROCEDURE Store*` вас не смущает? Это, походу, не паскаль.

Comment: @Alekcvp А при чем тут Паскаль?

Comment: @Harry, я о вашем комментарии, думал вас смутило название переменных. А если это не паскаль (хотя в тегах стоит паскаль), то N и n - вполне могут быть разные переменные.

Comment: @Alekcvp А, вот вы к чему... Я просто хотел понять, это реально язык, чувствительный к регистру, или нет. Тем более что та же * может быть очепяткой или из какого-нибудь диалекта Паскаля...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скорее всего отсутствие (вернее, наличие не везде) регистров приводило к тому, что языки были нечувствительны к регистру. Как Pascal - и, кстати, его производные Modula и Oberon - одним Виртом писанные :)

Ну, а дальше мог сыграть вопрос стиля - например, выделять ключевые слова прописными, переменные, например, строчными, а имена функций - "верблюжьим стилем"...

Comment: Скорее это пошло от старых языков программирования (FORTRAN 77, например) где зарезервированные слова были только в верхнем регистре (наследие перфокарт), а нижний можно было использовать только для идентификаторов. Поэтому когда паскаль и прочие только появлялись (или на них только переходили) многие писали так по привычке.

Comment: @Alekcvp Да как всегда - как в той истории про "так здесь принято"...

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю точного ответа, но сделаю предположение. Когда то вывод осуществлялся на монохромные мониторы и принтеры, с жестко забитой таблицей символов. Выделять начертанием, или тем более цветом, было невозможно. Поэтому выделение верхним регистром было одним из немногих средств форматирования, совместимых, к тому же, для разных устройств.